# If I'm trapped in $L_4$ or $L_5$ of Lagrange points, am I going to experience any libration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, oscillators, celestial-mechanics

I read that there are some points in space where the gravitational forces from the Sun and Earth get cancelled out, although I still not sure why L1, L2 & L3 are unstable compared to L4 & L5 even though all these massive objects move on the same plane! but never mind that for now, suppose I were to go to L4 and I no longer experiencing any acceleration then what will happen to me? will I be orbiting in a circle around L4 or spinning in circle due to the gravitational pitfall trap?

Comment: Of course [libration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libration) motion is possible if that's the question.